# Counting puzzle #1: Function combinations

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics

<sub>Not in conjunction with my function optimization puzzles, also sorry for the extremely difficult discrete mathematics puzzle</sub>

---

So as you may or may not know, I have recently uploaded [2 function optimization puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmathematics%5D+%5Boptimization%5D+user%3A86115) which were only part of the inspiration for this puzzle. The rest of the inspiration mostly came from [this comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/123194/minimum-function-optimization-puzzle-2#comment344036_123198) from @AxiomaticSystem:

> [image: [1 vote] If you want to make more of these, I'd like to see more functions at once - that would allow things like parity to come into play and make the solutions less straightforward. Additionally, I'm curious to see at what point lower limits like the -12 become obsolete. - AxiomaticSystem [14 hours ago]]

I know this was supposed to refer to my minimum function optimization puzzles, but I want to try something here before doing that. Here is the puzzle I have created here:

> Let$$\begin{align}f(n):=&\,n^2\\g(n):=&\,2n\\h(n):=&\,4n+1\end{align}$$and let set $\mathbb S$ be the set of pos. integers that can be achieved by applying any combination of $f$s, $g$s, and $h$s to 0. How many pos. integers $\le2048$ are in $\mathbb S$?

#### Things to mention

---

1. Partial answers are 100% allowed and are going to be encouraged on this question! This is because this is a really difficult problem and I don't want to discourage anyone from answering.
2. This took me around 1.5 hours to solve<sup>{1}</sup>, so I have been able to verify that there is an answer that can be reached for this puzzle.
3. To get the $\color{green}✓$, you have to show your work on how you got all of the numbers and the final answer.

---

Hint:

> This is also somewhat based off of [Blackpenredpen's modification of a 2020 Oxford math admissions question](https://youtu.be/9WKHZB76BN0), so this screenshot may come in handy when coming up with a strategy to solve it (from a deleted question of mine on Mathematics.SE that was asking if my solution to the aforementioned problem was correct):
>
>  [image]

---

<sub><sup>{1}</sup>without a brute force algorithm (I can't program *that* well), although I think those are allowed under the rules that I have stated as long as every number in $\mathbb S$ is printed and the alg. is given, although please try to solve it yourself first.</sub>

Comment: I really don't think you need the _not in conjunction with_ thing, because there's very little ambiguity or doubt that [puzzle _x_] goes with [puzzle _y_]. (As your titles are already always helpfully marked.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programmed solution:

> There are $274$ numbers in $\mathbb S$

These numbers are listed below, along with the function that produces them.

> #1: 1 = h(0)
>  #2: 2 = g(1)
>  #3: 4 = g(2)
>  #4: 5 = h(1)
>  #5: 8 = g(4)
>  #6: 9 = h(2)
>  #7: 10 = g(5)
>  #8: 16 = g(8)
>  #9: 17 = h(4)
>  #10: 18 = g(9)
>  #11: 20 = g(10)
>  #12: 21 = h(5)
>  #13: 25 = f(5)
>  #14: 32 = g(16)
>  #15: 33 = h(8)
>  #16: 34 = g(17)
>  #17: 36 = g(18)
>  #18: 37 = h(9)
>  #19: 40 = g(20)
>  #20: 41 = h(10)
>  #21: 42 = g(21)
>  #22: 50 = g(25)
>  #23: 64 = g(32)
>  #24: 65 = h(16)
>  #25: 66 = g(33)
>  #26: 68 = g(34)
>  #27: 69 = h(17)
>  #28: 72 = g(36)
>  #29: 73 = h(18)
>  #30: 74 = g(37)
>  #31: 80 = g(40)
>  #32: 81 = h(20)
>  #33: 82 = g(41)
>  #34: 84 = g(42)
>  #35: 85 = h(21)
>  #36: 100 = g(50)
>  #37: 101 = h(25)
>  #38: 128 = g(64)
>  #39: 129 = h(32)
>  #40: 130 = g(65)
>  #41: 132 = g(66)
>  #42: 133 = h(33)
>  #43: 136 = g(68)
>  #44: 137 = h(34)
>  #45: 138 = g(69)
>  #46: 144 = g(72)
>  #47: 145 = h(36)
>  #48: 146 = g(73)
>  #49: 148 = g(74)
>  #50: 149 = h(37)
>  #51: 160 = g(80)
>  #52: 161 = h(40)
>  #53: 162 = g(81)
>  #54: 164 = g(82)
>  #55: 165 = h(41)
>  #56: 168 = g(84)
>  #57: 169 = h(42)
>  #58: 170 = g(85)
>  #59: 200 = g(100)
>  #60: 201 = h(50)
>  #61: 202 = g(101)
>  #62: 256 = g(128)
>  #63: 257 = h(64)
>  #64: 258 = g(129)
>  #65: 260 = g(130)
>  #66: 261 = h(65)
>  #67: 264 = g(132)
>  #68: 265 = h(66)
>  #69: 266 = g(133)
>  #70: 272 = g(136)
>  #71: 273 = h(68)
>  #72: 274 = g(137)
>  #73: 276 = g(138)
>  #74: 277 = h(69)
>  #75: 288 = g(144)
>  #76: 289 = h(72)
>  #77: 290 = g(145)
>  #78: 292 = g(146)
>  #79: 293 = h(73)
>  #80: 296 = g(148)
>  #81: 297 = h(74)
>  #82: 298 = g(149)
>  #83: 320 = g(160)
>  #84: 321 = h(80)
>  #85: 322 = g(161)
>  #86: 324 = g(162)
>  #87: 325 = h(81)
>  #88: 328 = g(164)
>  #89: 329 = h(82)
>  #90: 330 = g(165)
>  #91: 336 = g(168)
>  #92: 337 = h(84)
>  #93: 338 = g(169)
>  #94: 340 = g(170)
>  #95: 341 = h(85)
>  #96: 400 = g(200)
>  #97: 401 = h(100)
>  #98: 402 = g(201)
>  #99: 404 = g(202)
>  #100: 405 = h(101)
>  #101: 441 = f(21)
>  #102: 512 = g(256)
>  #103: 513 = h(128)
>  #104: 514 = g(257)
>  #105: 516 = g(258)
>  #106: 517 = h(129)
>  #107: 520 = g(260)
>  #108: 521 = h(130)
>  #109: 522 = g(261)
>  #110: 528 = g(264)
>  #111: 529 = h(132)
>  #112: 530 = g(265)
>  #113: 532 = g(266)
>  #114: 533 = h(133)
>  #115: 544 = g(272)
>  #116: 545 = h(136)
>  #117: 546 = g(273)
>  #118: 548 = g(274)
>  #119: 549 = h(137)
>  #120: 552 = g(276)
>  #121: 553 = h(138)
>  #122: 554 = g(277)
>  #123: 576 = g(288)
>  #124: 577 = h(144)
>  #125: 578 = g(289)
>  #126: 580 = g(290)
>  #127: 581 = h(145)
>  #128: 584 = g(292)
>  #129: 585 = h(146)
>  #130: 586 = g(293)
>  #131: 592 = g(296)
>  #132: 593 = h(148)
>  #133: 594 = g(297)
>  #134: 596 = g(298)
>  #135: 597 = h(149)
>  #136: 625 = f(25)
>  #137: 640 = g(320)
>  #138: 641 = h(160)
>  #139: 642 = g(321)
>  #140: 644 = g(322)
>  #141: 645 = h(161)
>  #142: 648 = g(324)
>  #143: 649 = h(162)
>  #144: 650 = g(325)
>  #145: 656 = g(328)
>  #146: 657 = h(164)
>  #147: 658 = g(329)
>  #148: 660 = g(330)
>  #149: 661 = h(165)
>  #150: 672 = g(336)
>  #151: 673 = h(168)
>  #152: 674 = g(337)
>  #153: 676 = g(338)
>  #154: 677 = h(169)
>  #155: 680 = g(340)
>  #156: 681 = h(170)
>  #157: 682 = g(341)
>  #158: 800 = g(400)
>  #159: 801 = h(200)
>  #160: 802 = g(401)
>  #161: 804 = g(402)
>  #162: 805 = h(201)
>  #163: 808 = g(404)
>  #164: 809 = h(202)
>  #165: 810 = g(405)
>  #166: 882 = g(441)
>  #167: 1024 = g(512)
>  #168: 1025 = h(256)
>  #169: 1026 = g(513)
>  #170: 1028 = g(514)
>  #171: 1029 = h(257)
>  #172: 1032 = g(516)
>  #173: 1033 = h(258)
>  #174: 1034 = g(517)
>  #175: 1040 = g(520)
>  #176: 1041 = h(260)
>  #177: 1042 = g(521)
>  #178: 1044 = g(522)
>  #179: 1045 = h(261)
>  #180: 1056 = g(528)
>  #181: 1057 = h(264)
>  #182: 1058 = g(529)
>  #183: 1060 = g(530)
>  #184: 1061 = h(265)
>  #185: 1064 = g(532)
>  #186: 1065 = h(266)
>  #187: 1066 = g(533)
>  #188: 1088 = g(544)
>  #189: 1089 = h(272)
>  #190: 1090 = g(545)
>  #191: 1092 = g(546)
>  #192: 1093 = h(273)
>  #193: 1096 = g(548)
>  #194: 1097 = h(274)
>  #195: 1098 = g(549)
>  #196: 1104 = g(552)
>  #197: 1105 = h(276)
>  #198: 1106 = g(553)
>  #199: 1108 = g(554)
>  #200: 1109 = h(277)
>  #201: 1152 = g(576)
>  #202: 1153 = h(288)
>  #203: 1154 = g(577)
>  #204: 1156 = g(578)
>  #205: 1157 = h(289)
>  #206: 1160 = g(580)
>  #207: 1161 = h(290)
>  #208: 1162 = g(581)
>  #209: 1168 = g(584)
>  #210: 1169 = h(292)
>  #211: 1170 = g(585)
>  #212: 1172 = g(586)
>  #213: 1173 = h(293)
>  #214: 1184 = g(592)
>  #215: 1185 = h(296)
>  #216: 1186 = g(593)
>  #217: 1188 = g(594)
>  #218: 1189 = h(297)
>  #219: 1192 = g(596)
>  #220: 1193 = h(298)
>  #221: 1194 = g(597)
>  #222: 1250 = g(625)
>  #223: 1280 = g(640)
>  #224: 1281 = h(320)
>  #225: 1282 = g(641)
>  #226: 1284 = g(642)
>  #227: 1285 = h(321)
>  #228: 1288 = g(644)
>  #229: 1289 = h(322)
>  #230: 1290 = g(645)
>  #231: 1296 = g(648)
>  #232: 1297 = h(324)
>  #233: 1298 = g(649)
>  #234: 1300 = g(650)
>  #235: 1301 = h(325)
>  #236: 1312 = g(656)
>  #237: 1313 = h(328)
>  #238: 1314 = g(657)
>  #239: 1316 = g(658)
>  #240: 1317 = h(329)
>  #241: 1320 = g(660)
>  #242: 1321 = h(330)
>  #243: 1322 = g(661)
>  #244: 1344 = g(672)
>  #245: 1345 = h(336)
>  #246: 1346 = g(673)
>  #247: 1348 = g(674)
>  #248: 1349 = h(337)
>  #249: 1352 = g(676)
>  #250: 1353 = h(338)
>  #251: 1354 = g(677)
>  #252: 1360 = g(680)
>  #253: 1361 = h(340)
>  #254: 1362 = g(681)
>  #255: 1364 = g(682)
>  #256: 1365 = h(341)
>  #257: 1369 = f(37)
>  #258: 1600 = g(800)
>  #259: 1601 = h(400)
>  #260: 1602 = g(801)
>  #261: 1604 = g(802)
>  #262: 1605 = h(401)
>  #263: 1608 = g(804)
>  #264: 1609 = h(402)
>  #265: 1610 = g(805)
>  #266: 1616 = g(808)
>  #267: 1617 = h(404)
>  #268: 1618 = g(809)
>  #269: 1620 = g(810)
>  #270: 1621 = h(405)
>  #271: 1681 = f(41)
>  #272: 1764 = g(882)
>  #273: 1765 = h(441)
>  #274: 2048 = g(1024)

C code to identify and count the numbers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int S[2049];
  int n,t;
  for(n=0;n<2049;++n)S[n]=0; // initialize
  S[1]=1; // mark h(0) = 1 in S
  for(n=t=0;n<2049;++n){
    if(S[n]){ // if n is in S
      ++t;
      if(n<46) S[n*n]=1; // mark f(n) in S
      if(n<1025) S[n+n]=1; // mark g(n) in S
      if(n<512) S[4*n+1]=1; // mark h(n) in S
    }
  }
  printf("%d",t);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Computerless solution**

There are

> 274 numbers

in the set S.

Let's first of all consider

> just the functions g,h, which append `0` and `01` respectively to the binary representation of their arguments.
>  By starting with 0 and iterating these we can get any number *whose binary representation has no two consecutive 1s*.
>  These aren't too painful to enumerate by hand: once we've found all of them below
>  each power of 2 up to 2^n, we get the next block by adding 2^n to all the ones below 2^(n-1).
>  But we don't actually need to enumerate them, we just need (1) to know how many there are
>  and (2) to be able to recognize them. For (1), it's not hard to see that the number
>  of these below 2^n is F(n+2), the (n+2)'th Fibonacci number. For (2), we can just look at
>  the binary representation of any number we're curious about.
>  So, we have F_13 = 233 of these below 2048, and hence 234 of them up to 2048 inclusive.

Well, actually

> we do need to enumerate the first few -- as we'll see in the next paragraph,
>  we need the ones up to 45. So, in blocks corresponding to powers of 2 as described above:
>  0 | 1 | 2 | 4 5 | 8 9 10 | 16 17 18 20 21 | 32 33 34 36 37 40 41 42 | 64 ...

Anyway, we aren't done yet, because

> some squares of these numbers might not be of the required form.
>  To be < 2048 they'd need to be squares of numbers <= 45,
>  so let's square the first few numbers in the list above:
>  0 1 4 16 **25** 64 81 **100** 256 289 324 **400** **441** 1024 1089 1156 1296 **1369** **1600** **1681** **1764**.

We now have

> 8 new numbers, for a total of 242 so far.

Now we need to augment our list by

> appending "0"s and "01"s to these, with a limit of 2048 as usual.
>  None of the numbers this yields can be in our list of 234 numbers
>  because they all have two adjacent 1s.
>  From 25 we get 50, (100), 101, 200, 201, 202,
>  (400), 401, 402, 404, 405, 800, 801, 802, 804, 805, 808, 809, 810,
>  (1600), 1601, 1602, 1604, 1605, 1608, 1609, 1610, 1616, 1617, 1618, 1620, 1621.
>  That's 29 new numbers, taking us to 271.
>  From 100 and 400 we get only things we already got from 25.
>  From 441 we get 882, (1764), 1765: 2 new numbers, taking us to 273.
>  The next new square is 1369, and anything obtained from that is > 2048.

We're still not *quite* done because we need to consider

> squaring our new numbers.
>  That gets us 625 (which, having adjacent 1s in its binary representation and not being one of the numbers we've just written down, is new), and hence also 1250.
>  Now we're on 275,

and *now* we're done, except that I have included the 0 with which we start and the question asks about *positive* integers, so the required answer is actually 1 less.

Comment: Zero is not in S

Comment: Yeah, you're right. (As it happens I'd just spotted that myself, on comparing my answer with yours which is almost the same but produces a value off by one.) I was fooled by the "starting with 0" in the process :-). [EDITED to add:] Fixed now.

Comment: As it happens, I *just* completed the manual solution myself, and was about to edit my answer... :o(

Comment: Oh no! I'm sorry. But not _very_ sorry. :-)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Good job on the first computerless solution! :D Guess I wasn't expecting an answer from [math themself](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52642/mathematics-function-building-contest#comment161458_52654)!

Answer (score 1):

Computer Assisted Solution:

Answer:

> There are 229 numbers in $\mathbb S$

Algorithm:

> 4 Columns in Excel n, F(n), G(n), H(n).
>  n goes from 1-2048, the rest are calculated.
>  So, the first row, is everything you can calculate with n=1 (1, 2, 5)
>  This means 2 is a valid row, and yields (4,4,9).
>  For any row to be valid, its n value MUST exist as a result in the previous rows.  If it doesn't, it can't be calculated.
>  Row 3 can be deleted, as 3 does not exist as a previous result.
>  You can do this manually, or add a few extra columns and use some clever `lookup()` and `find()` functions and set a flag indicating if a row is valid or not.

Comment: good job!! Don't worry, that's the correct answer! :) although I really doubt it's solvable normally without it taking an extremely long amount of time tbh